# Intel compiler segmentation violation when compiling using -openmp and -ipo with Cray LibSci on Cray XC30

Tags: compilation, fortran, openmp, cray

I am compiling a code that uses Cray LibSci numerical library for BLAS and LAPACK on a Cray XC30 system using the Intel compiler with the "-ipo" flag and including "-openmp" to compile OpenMP-enabled code.

I see the following error for any code I try to compile:

```
** segmentation violation signal raised **
Access violation or stack overflow. Please contact Support.

ifort: error #10106: Fatal error in /opt/intel/composer_xe_2013_sp1.4.211/bin/intel64/fortcom, terminated by segmentation violation
ifort: error #10014: problem during multi-file optimization compilation (code 1)
```

This can be illustrated with a very simple example:

```
user@eslogin008:~> cat blas1F.f
      program blas1F

      implicit none

      real*4 x(4), y(4)

      external sswap

      data x/2, 3, 4, 5/
      data y/5, 4, 9, 2/

      call sswap(4,   x, 1,   y, 1)

      write (*,*) 'After Swap..'

      end
```

Compiling:

```
user@eslogin008:~> ftn -ipo -openmp blas1F.f
** segmentation violation signal raised **
Access violation or stack overflow. Please contact Support.

ifort: error #10106: Fatal error in /opt/intel/composer_xe_2013_sp1.4.211/bin/intel64/fortcom, terminated by segmentation violation
ifort: error #10014: problem during multi-file optimization compilation (code 1)
```

Excluding either one of the "-ipo" or "-openmp" flags results in the code compiling and running fine.

Answer (score 0):

It is the threaded (OpenMP) version of the Cray LibSci library that is causing the problem here. One workaround is to link the non-threaded version of the library by adding "-lsci_intel":

```
user@eslogin008:~> ftn -ipo -openmp -lsci_intel blas1F.f
ipo: remark #11001: performing single-file optimizations
ipo: remark #11006: generating object file /tmp/ipo_ifortcBBetG.o
```

Comment: Looks like a compiler bug to me. Notify Cray about it.

Comment: @HristoIliev I think Andy notified both the compiler and library vendors. Andy, thanks for investigating the problem.

Comment: Cray are working on understanding what is going wrong here and are trying to determine if this is a bug with their library, with the Intel compiler, or both.

Comment: It's the Intel compiler, and the -ipo phase in particular that is having issues. It tries reading the libraries (to see if there is any Intel intermediate code) and is running into a problem. Is this reproducible with a current Intel compiler version (15.0.4 is current)? If so, please report to Intel, or Cray if they provide your support (Cray will then work with us.)